# ajax multiple file upload

Tags: php, jquery

im trying to build a ajax multiple file upload because i found every plugin too complicated to configure, i started with a multi file upload in php, but i see that if i have too many file to upload at once when i submit the form it will take too much time to end, how is this latence handled? is this handled with jquery iframe transport?
http://cmlenz.github.com/jquery-iframe-transport/

```
$("#myform").submit(function() {
    $.ajax(this.action, {
        data: $(":text", this).serializeArray(),
        files: $(":file", this),
        iframe: true,
        processData: false
    }).complete(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

thanks

Comment: Try http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxForm

Comment: What on earth are you asking?

Comment: if you submit too many files at once, uploading them to the server will take time, how is this handled with plugin who dont take long in uploading many files?

Comment: You cannot magically make the server or connection faster.

Comment: ok but if you uplaod with this plugin:
http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload
the multiple upload will be faster.

Comment: If every plugin you found was too complicated to configure, how complicated do you think the programming of such a plugin is? Generally speaking, if it's difficult to configure, it'll be exponentially harder to code in the first place. Use something like this (http://valums.com/ajax-upload/); don't recreate the wheel.

Comment: To handle many uploads, a solution is to create a stack/queue, and limit the number of uploads at a given time. Like 5 uploads max at a time. Everytime one is finished, you start a new one until your upload queue is empty... but as wanovak said, it's better to spend some time configuring an existing upload script than to recreate a new one... even if I agree with you, setting up a multi-upload is rarely easy...

Answer (score 0):

These plugins use the new HTML5 file API to upload multiple files in parallel, with one POST per file.

By contrast, `<iframe>`-based uploaders send a normal `<form>` POST, which creates a single POST for everything and uploads the files in sequence.